# Select dates from today and in the future from table

Tags: mysql

Alot of people are asking how you can `select` all dates in your `table` and all the dates that will come for the next year.

I got a solution for that and it is really simple (Probably not the best one though), that I would like to share with you.

Comment: where/what is your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no solutions provided.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 'date_field' FROM `Table` 
WHERE 'date_field' BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND CURRENT_DATE() +10000
ORDER BY 'date_field' ASC
```

This Query will give you all your `date_field` of your `table` `between` the `date` of today: (2018-04-06) and the `date` of next year: (2019-04-06) in `Ascending` order.

The `+ 10000` is a whole year.

So `+ 5000` would be half a year.

This is just a little solution to Select all your dates from today and a year in the future.

Comment: i bet it won't since CURRENT_DATE() is a **function** and you don't specify a column on that function for comparison...so it simply will output all data no matter what the condition is since the condition is always true!

Comment: i tested it in a table where no date column is present...and it worked because of the facts given in the previous comment. it doesn't make any sense at all, sorry. i would downvote if i could...

Comment: @meistermuh I am sorry, I edited it. now it does work I missed the BETWEEN I didnt copied it when I answered the question

Comment: @meistermuh Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: now it makes more sense ;) 

however, `current_date() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR` could be better instead of +10000 since that might cause a problem in a leapyear